# Opera onkeyup broken? Repeats, fires while down

Tags: javascript, mootools, opera, mootools-events

When I add any `onkeyup` event, it does not do what it's supposed to in Opera. It fires repeatedly while the key is held, not when it's released. This same event works correctly in Chrome and Firefox. I have no listeners for `keydown` or `keypressed`.

This simple code logs a stream of key events to the console in Opera when the key is held down. In Firefox and Chrome, it logs a single line when the key is released (I'm using Mootools, but it does the same with traditional event attaching, and does it attached anywhere: window, document, a text field...)

```
        $(window).addEvent("keyup", trapKeyUp);
        function trapKeyUp(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
```

**So my question is: is there something I'm doing wrong code wise in Opera's case, or is the browser just horribly broken?** In searching on this site and Google I did not readily find any references to this specific issue. I'm using the latest Opera on Ubuntu.

Comment: Can't replicate on Windows. `keyup` works fine. No Ubuntu to hand, sorry.

Comment: "Latest Opera" meaning the stable 10.60, or the experimental 10.70? (the experimental 10.70 builds are, well, not quite stable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that Opera doesn't repeat keyup events on Windows, so it seems like an error (a bug) in the integration with the Ubuntu platform. If it is still a problem in a 10.70 preview build please report a bug at https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/ - if you give me the bug's reference number I can push it forward.

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone and sorry I was a slowpoke getting back to this. Yes, I was using the stable version, I should have been more clear about that. I went ahead and submitted a bug the other day (woops) but I'll check out the beta build and submit a proper bug if needed ;) (The number of the bug I submitted is DSK-315301, which you may or may not want to throw out!). As far as my question goes, though, I'm satisfied that it's only a bug and not a problem with my code.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with this running opera for linux, the keyup is indeed triggered at a rate according to the auto-repeat set in the OS. I tested around, and opera on linux is the only browser still doing this, I think it was more common earlier.

I filed a bug for this earlier, reference id `DSK-307269` if helps.

PS: It was a couple of months ago, so it might've been fixed since, but I assume you're on the latest, so not the case.

From email auto-generated when bug reported:

> You can use this e-mail address (or reply to this e-mail) to update your report with more information, such as screenshots, crash logs, code examples, and so on:
>
> DSK-307269@bugs.opera.com.
>
> This is the information you submitted to us:
> Version: 10.60
> Build: 6386
> Operating system: Linux
> Platform: PC
>
> Summary: keyup js-event repeated while key stays down

Answer (score 0):

it's still happen on Opera 11.50 under Ubuntu.. not really an issue though, but kinda annoying to know that your code doesn't work the same way across browser and/or operating system. i use this event (onkeyup) to prevent user sending very rapid request to the server, and making it hung on slower network.

Comment: It does indeed still happen, but I hope we'll get this bug squashed for Opera 12. Sorry about any inconvenience meanwhile.

Comment: Seem that it still happen. Several months later :(

Version 12.14 
Build 1738 
Platform Linux

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061518/opera-12-on-debian-gnu-linux-keyup-event